# Escaping Characters in Python Variables

Tags: python, escaping

I have a list of names that I scrape form a site using python and add to a database. All works well except for the occasional name that has a ' in it. I understand have to use escape characters in a specific string when I know where the character is but is there a way to escape any character that might be in a string without knowing if they are are there or not?

For example, in the following code I need to escape special characters in the `name` variable:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO players (name, position, team, status) values ('%s', '%s', %s, %s)""" % (name, position, team, status))
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: I am unclear why you believe this is relevant, please explain. First and for most I see no mention of escaping for python in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is to pass the arguments in a tuple to `cursor.execute`:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO players (name, position, team, status) values (%s, %s, %s, %s)""", (name, position, team, status))
```

And let the cursor do the escaping.